# How to find a parent with a child excluding another in mysql?

Tags: mysql

[image]
An item has many tags through the taggables table. In MYSQL, how do I search for items tagged as "Blue" that aren't also tagged as "Square"?

Comment: Take a look at this ancient example http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507748,507839.  Come back if you have any further questions (preferably with proper DDLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT items.* FROM items
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM item_has_tags
        WHERE item_id=items.id AND name='square')
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM item_has_tags
        WHERE item_id=items.id AND name='blue');
```

To simplify things a bit you can create a view

```
CREATE VIEW item_has_tags AS
     SELECT * FROM taggables 
          JOIN tags ON (taggables.tag_id = tags.id);
```

and the query then becomes,

```
SELECT items.* FROM items WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM item_has_tags WHERE item_id=items.id AND name='square')
AND NOT
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item_has_tags WHERE item_id=items.id AND name='blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a subquery that returns the ids of the records you want to commit:

```
select i.*
from items as i
left join (
    select distinct tg.item_id
    from taggables as tg
    inner join tags as t on tg.tag_id = t.id
    where t.name = 'square'
    ) as a on I.id = a.item_Id
where a.item_id is null and i.name = 'blue';
```

Comment: @Iserni Indeed! Sorry for the typo. Just corrected it